# Webpack doesn't generate bundle.js via build.js

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-2, dev-to-production

I try to build a production `bundle.js` with `webpack.config.prod.js`, but when I run `npm run build` command, it executes `prebuild` script and stops on `build` script and not even tries to run it. Therefore, it doesn't create `bundle.js` at all.

I follow an example with `webpack v1` and I try to migrate to `v2` and understand why the running of `build.js` doesn't work.

These are my files:

### package.json

```
{      
  "scripts": {        
    "lint": "esw webpack.config.* src buildScripts",        
    "test": "mocha --reporter progress buildScripts/testSetup.js \"src/**/*.test.js\"",        
    "clean-dist": "rimraf ./dist && mkdir dist",

// Executes prebuild script

    "prebuild": "npm-run-all clean-dist test lint",

// Stops on build script

    "build": "babel-node buildScripts/build.js",
    "postbuild": "babel-node buildScripts/distServer.js"
  },      
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.0",        
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",              
    "eslint": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-watch": "^3.1.2",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "jsdom": "^11.1.0",        
    "json-server": "^0.11.2",        
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.2",        
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

### webpack.config.prod.js

```
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';

module.exports = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.js")
    ],
    target: "web",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        publicPath: "/",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    devServer: {
        noInfo: false
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            debug: true
        }),
        //Minify JS
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ["babel-loader"]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

### build.js

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackConfig from '../webpack.config.prod';    

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

console.log('Generating minified bundle for production. This will take a moment...');

webpack(webpackConfig).run((err, stats) => {
    if (err) {            
        console.log(err);
        return 1;
    }        

    return 0;
});
```

Comment: Does the `prebuild` script finish successfully (is the exit code 0)?

Comment: @MichaelJungo `prebuild` finishes with success, but `build` isn't running at all. If it was, there should be a 'Generating minified bundle for production. This will take a moment...'  message in the terminal.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `prebuild` script?

Comment: @MichaelJungo Yes! It does. Why is it? What is the matter with `prebuild` script?

Comment: It must be finishing with an error. To help you diagnose the issue, you need to post the output of the command.

Comment: @MichaelJungo Thank you for your help. The errors in the `lint` script. They can be removed by changing `eslint` configurations.